# Is there a method to estimate the recovery time of a SQL Server 2005 database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, recovery

I am looking at a large-ish SQL Server 2005 database, that has entered into Recovery mode, and I am wondering if there is any way to estimate how long it's going to be until the database has recovered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any more than a few seconds means an outage during a multi-million update row that needs undone.
You'll have to follow progress in the SQL error log.

Slightly cheeky, but you could read "[Understanding Recovery Performance in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189262(SQL.90).aspx)" while you wait...

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the server logs, it will add a log entry after every 1% of progress or so.  From that you can guestimate the time left.  It's usually what I end up having to do.

Comment: The easiest place to access them is under Management\SQL Server Logs in the object explorer in SSMS

Comment: SQL Script to estimate time http://timlaqua.com/2009/09/determining-how-long-a-database-will-be-in-recovery-sql-server-2008/